# Find XML element available using xlint -- xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

This is my XML, I am working using `xmllint` (parsing xml in a bash script file) to find element presence in a xml.

```
<testsuite name="com.myapp.testcases.loginTest">

    <testcase name="invalidIdTest" classname="com.myapp.testcases.loginTest" time="0.002">
        <skipped/>
    </testcase>

    <testcase name="invalidTokenTest" classname="com.myapp.testcases.loginTest" time="4.164"/>

    <testcase name="connectAndDisconnectTest" classname="com.myapp.testcases.loginTest" time="13.622">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="invalidServerUrlTest" classname="com.myapp.testcases.loginTest" time="40.072"/>
</testsuite>
```

I want to find out `testcase` element whether has child element `skipped` or not?
If I tried following command but its gives empty output for all the 4 `testcase` elements.

```
val=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(testsuite/testcase/*[local-name()="skipped"])' skipped.xml)
echo $val
```

and triied this also

```
isSkipped=$(xmllint --xpath "string(/testsuite/testcase[$i][skipped])" skipped.xml)
```

I want to do print 1 if `testcase` element has `skipped` child element otherwise 0.
please help me on that

Answer (score 0):

> I want to do print 1 if `testcase` element has `skipped` child element
>   otherwise 0

```
number(boolean(/testsuite/testcase[skipped]))
```

Do note that this works for the whole document: "is there any `testcase` with `skipped` child".